# Ember.js how to get a model inside beforeModel/afterModel hooks and pass it to the controller?

Tags: ember.js

I have a problem getting the `models` inside a `controller` of a route accessed using `{{link-to}}`
From my understanding (after reading http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/) the `model` hook of a `route` doesn't get called when the route is accessed from a `{{link-to 'route' model}}`. The `model` is passed directly to the `controller`. This is a way that Ember ensures that no `AJAX` called will be made unnecessarily.

For example if I go to `{{link-to 'post-review' post}}` and I need to pass more than a `post model` to the `PostReviewController`.

```
App.Router.map(function () {
 ...
 this.resource('post-review' , {path: '/post-review/:id'});
 ...
});

PostReviewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  //method doesn't get called
  model: function(params){
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
        post: this.store.find('post', params.id),
        reviewTypes: this.store.find('reviewType')
    });
  }
});
```

The `ReviewType`is a model which has no relationship with `Post` so that I can access it directly using `post.reviewType`. A `post` has several `reviews`. A review has a `reviewType`. But I must show all the `reviewTypes` inside of a combobox.

Anyways, the `model` hook doesn't get called and I cannot access the `this.get('reviewTypes')` from `PostReviewController`. I understand that the `beforeModel` or `afterModel` hooks are used for this purpose: to pass additional `models` to a `controller` when the `route` it's accessed from a `link-to` and not directly from the browser URL. The documentation doesn't show how you can do that! Please enlighten me if you know how!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[setupController](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/) to the rescue, in your route use the setupController hook to set the reviewTypes like so:

```
PostReviewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
   var postId = model.get('id');
   this._super.apply(this, arguments);
   this.store.find('reviewType').then((records)=> {
     controller.set('reviewTypes', records);
   });
   this.store.find('post', postId).then(....)
  },
// your code
});
```

You should now be able to call `this.get('reviewTypes')`.

Let me know if this does it for you.

Comment: Oups one thing that slipped my mind, I m using esNext, replace `(records)=>...` with `function(records)...` in case you aren't ^^

Comment: It works! But now it's a bit confusing how I can access the post and reviewTypes form inside the controller, using this.get('reviewTypes'). However I cannot access the post; this.get('post') is undefined. Something is missing..

Comment: Edited, on a side note, `this.resource('post-review' , {path: '/post-review/:id'});` should be `this.resource('post-review' , {path: '/post-review/:post_id'});`

Comment: Thanks you very much, Patsy! It drove me nuts! :) BTW, I guess that model: function(){} even if it gets called when the page is refreshed (or I enter the URL directly into the browser) doesn't make sense anymore..